# Problems connecting a monitor via HDMI to my Lenovo Thinkpad T460S

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, lock-screen, vga

My laptop is **Lenovo thinkpad T460s** with **Ubuntu 16.04** running with GNOME desktop environment. I am facing an issue when attempting to use dual monitors; Whenever I connect any monitor through HDMI port, the lock screen starts flashing after entering the password, and the password box disappears with some of the icons at the top bar. Then I unplug it, log in in, then I plug the monitor and the folders move to the other screen.

I have tried most of the popular fixes mentioned on the network since since 2011 and none of them worked (i.e. tried to define commands at the startup using the `xrandr` command, tried to define some scripts that force the setup of the primary and secondary screens, and much more like deleting the `~/.config/monitors.xml` and/or copying/linking it to `/var/lib/lightdm/.config/`).

**The monitor is being connected with the option above my laptop's screen.**

Some information that could be helpful:

```
$ sudo lspci|grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake 
Integrated Graphics (rev 07)

$ sudo lshw -C display
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:126 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can I fix this?